# Error al enviar un arreglo de objetos por Postman

Tags: nodejs, postman, depuración, headers

Estoy tratando de enviar un arreglo de Objetos Javascript a través de PostMan a mi Backend. Los registros están siendo insertados en la BD, sin embargo, en la consola de Node me sale este error.

```
Unhandled rejection Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:485:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:767:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\controllers\ph\personas.js:9:5
    at C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\models\ph\personas.js:66:13
    at tryCatcher (C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:512:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:569:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:614:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:690:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:138:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:131:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:147:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\PHorizontal\PCI\ph-pci-back\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:17:14)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
```

Cabe aclarar que si yo mando un solo objeto, no pasa nada.

La función que recorre el arreglo es esta:

```
exports.crear_personas = (req, resp_cb) => {
  req.body.items.forEach(element => {
    let valid = Joi.validate(element, PERSONAS_SCHEMA);
    let sps_json = JSON.stringify(element)
    if (valid.error != null) {
      resp_cb(null, {
        success: false,
        mensaje: 'Parámetros invalidos',
        error: valid.error.details
      });
      return;
    }
    database.query(`
      call pbd_crear_tbl_personas(
        :nombre,
        :identificacion,
        :rut,
        :alias,
        :primernombre,
        :segundonombre,
        :primerapellido,
        :segundoapellido,
        :correoelectronico,
        :celular,
        :direccion,
        :telefonooficina,
        :extensionoficina,
        :telefonocasa,
        @resultado
      )`, 
      {
        replacements: valid.value
      })
      .then(resultado => {
        return database.query('select @resultado as resultado;');
      })
      .then(resultado => {
        if (resultado != null && resultado != undefined && resultado.length > 0) {
          let success = resultado[0][0].resultado == 'OK';
          resp_cb(null, {
            success: success,
            mensaje: (success ? 'Registro insertado' : 'No se almacenó el registro\n' + resultado[0][0].resultado)
          });
        }
        else {
          resp_cb(null, {
            success: false,
            mensaje: 'No se pudo insertar el registro.\n' + resultado[0][0].resultado
          });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        resp_cb(null, {
          success: true,
          mensaje: 'Error creando el registro', error
      });
    });
  });
}
```

De paso, quiero saber cómo puedo depurar código JS en Visual Studio Code, para saber dónde es que se me está estallando el programa.

Lo que envío por Postman es esto:

```
{
  items": [
    {
      "nombre": "asd",
      "identificacion": "asd",
      "rut": "asd",
      "alias": "ddfg",
      "primernombre": "asdasd",
      "segundonombre": null,
      "primerapellido": "dfg",
      "segundoapellido": "dfg",
      "correoelectronico": "adfsdf",
      "celular": "asdfadf",
      "direccion": "Av 132",
      "telefonooficina": "7877788",
      "extensionoficina": "145",
      "telefonocasa": "7619066"
    },
    {
      "nombre": "sdafasdf",
      "identificacion": "asdf",
      "rut": "sadfsdf",
      "alias": "ZasRY",
      "primernombre": "adfsdf",
      "segundonombre": asdf,
      "primerapellido": "sadf",
      "segundoapellido": "asdf",
      "correoelectronico": "adsf@asdf",
      "celular": "asdf",
      "direccion": "Av 132",
      "telefonooficina": "7877788",
      "extensionoficina": "145",
      "telefonocasa": "7619066",
      "test": "true"
    },
    {
      "nombre": "wqerqwe",
      "identificacion": "wqer",
      "rut": "wqer",
      "alias": "SFM",
      "primernombre": "qwer",
      "segundonombre": null,
      "primerapellido": "qwer",
      "segundoapellido": "qewr",
      "correoelectronico": "qwerqwer",
      "celular": "3192878538",
      "direccion": "Av 132",
      "telefonooficina": "7877788",
      "extensionoficina": "145",
      "telefonocasa": "7619066",
      "test": "true"
    }
  ]
}
```

He tratado de meterle `async/await` pero no me funciona. Porque al parecer el error está al hacer

```
return database.query('select @resultado as resultado;');
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir lo que hace tu método `resp_cb` que estas pasando por referencia? Dices: *Cabe aclarar que si yo mando un solo objeto, no pasa nada*. Por lo que asumo a que te refieres que envías un solo elemento en tu `array`. La respuesta la tengo, pero necesito asegurarme de ver el código de tu método, para poder hablar con fundamento. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Esta linea `if (valid.error != null) {.... return}` no termina la ejecución de la promesa, solo te esta pasando al siguiente `then`. Dentro de `resp_cb` estas mandando la respuesta pero se siguen ejecutando los demas `then` hasta que se vuelve a lanzar otro `resp_cb`.

Yo haría lo siguiente:

```
if (valid.error != null) {
      throw {
        success: false,
        mensaje: 'Parámetros invalidos',
        error: valid.error.details
      }
    }
```

Y ahora si, capturo en el `catch`:

```
.catch(error => {
        resp_cb(null, error)
};
```

El comportamientos que señalas es debido a que tus datos no pasan la validación. Cuando pasa la validación no se ejecuta ese `if`